# When should XMLHttpRequest's onerror handler fire

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a little problem understanding `XMLHttpRequest`'s handlers. [The specification says this about the `onerror` handler](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#event-xhr-error):

> `error`   [Dispatched ... ] When the request has failed.
>
> `load`    [Dispatched ... ] When the request has successfully completed.

The problem is, what does it mean that "the request has failed". That could be

- the request couldn't be issued at all (eg. Connection refused and such errors), or
- the above plus the server returned an error code (eg. 404)

Also, I'd like to know whether it means `onerror` and `onload` should never fire simultaneously.

[This reference](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/ajax.shtml) indicates the `onerror` handler should be executed depending on the `status` code and `onload` depending on `readyState`. That would indicate they are not mutually exclusive, however, I don't think this is an authoritative information.

I'm asking because using the latest Opera snapshot, I found `onload` is fired even on 404 status code. I know testing `status` is a sure bet, but I'd like to know whether it's something I have to do per specification or just a workaround for a bug in Opera.

Comment: I take `has completed successfully` to mean that you receive a status code, whether that be 200 OK or an error code such as 404. Chrome also fires onload even if the status code is an error status code.

Comment: onerror and onload never fire simultaneously. It's either one or the other. However onloadend fires in both cases and is the last event in the row.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `onerror` fires when there is a failure on the *network level*. If the error only exists on the application level, e.g., an HTTP error code is sent, then `onload` still fires.  You need to test the returned status code explicitly in your `onreadystatechange` handler.

Note that a denied cross-domain request will also fire the `onerror` handler.

Comment: Hmm, strange. Can you (or anybody) explain that behavior of google server?

Comment: I did a more complete test and discovered that encrypted.google.com doesn't send 404 for that request -- the `status` member of the XHR request is actually `0`, where other servers send a 404.  Apparently that server suddenly pretends that it doesn't exist at all when it sees a request for a page that doesn't exist.  Weird, but that's Google's decision.

Comment: Or... it could be because hitting `https://encrypted.google.com/foobar` redirects to `http://www.google.com/foobar`, and the browser is refusing to participate in a cross-domain redirect during an Ajax request.

Comment: That would be it. The browser sends a request to `http://www.google.com/foobar`, sees there is no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the reply and refuses to give anything to the script.

Comment: How do you distinguish *what* network level failure occurred?  Several that I can think of are: DNS lookup failed, connection refused, timed out trying to contact server, timed out waiting for reply, denied due to CORS, and connection terminated abnormally.

Comment: I'm more curious where you got this particular piece of knowledge. Some documentation somewhere? Or even the source code? I'm having the same question today and realized I don't know where I should turn to.

Comment: @yaobin XHR behavior is specified by the [WHATWG XHR spec](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/) which occasionally links to the WHATWG Fetch spec for some CORS behavior. Might be worth searching through for every time the term `error` appears, as a starting place.

Comment: @apsillers Ah I found it [here](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-network-error): `A response whose type is "error" is known as a network error.`

Answer (score 3):

In addition to apsillers' answer, note that XMLHttpRequest handles redirects automatically in the background, so you don't have to check for this reply codes in the `onload` event (this event will be invoked only once - on the final call). Also note, that in case you send payload data with the POST method and if the requests is redirected, XMLHttpRequest change the method from `POST` to `GET` and discards any payload data for security reasons. The `onload` event will still be invoked but you will need to re-send your request manually again to the new destination.