# What HTTP status codes fire error event on XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, error-handling, event-handling, xmlhttprequest, dom-events

I've read every spec I can find, even the W3 for ProgressEvents as well as `XMLHttpRequest`,  and I'm finding diddly regarding WHICH status codes (or What response) fire an Error event on an async XHR request. The most I can find is references to checking the status code itself on the object and handling that, which normally treats anything but 200 as an Error, yet a 3xx redirect from, say, a POST is not an Error (I can't recall if the XHR will follow a redirect automatically) Can someone help me out or point me in the right direction regarding the spec (no libraries) for all responses that initiate an `onerror` event?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`onerror` only fires for network-level events, which means that `onload` will fire if there is a successful response, regardless of HTTP status code. See this question for more discussion: [When should XMLHttpRequest's onerror handler fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584318/when-should-xmlhttprequests-onerror-handler-fire)

Comment: Thanks, I searched quite awhile before asking assuming I wouldn't be the first to wonder, and the W3C spec is written so obtusely. Oh well, good to know