# Promise does not catch an error

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise, addeventlistener

```
function getJSON(url){
    return new Promise(function(resolveFN, crashFN){
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.responseType = 'json';
        processing(); //this is for special notifcation appear
        request.onload = function(e){
            resolveFN(request.response);
            removeProcessing(); //this is for special notifcation disappear after 'onload'
        };

        request.onerror = function(){
            debugger; //this is not invoked when url is wrong
            crashFN(new Error(' Couldn\'t load at: ' + url));
        };

        request.send();
    });
}
```

next when I use eventListener - it doesn't catch an error:

```
var prev = document.getElementById('prev');

prev.addEventListener('click', function(){
    getJSON('http://marsweather.ingenology.com/v1/archive/1').then(function(response){
        debugger; //this is invoked
        console.log(response);
    }).catch(function(err){
        debugger; // and this is not invoked. why?
        console.log('errrrrrrer ', err);
    });
});
```

What could be the reason that catch doesn't work inside the eventListener?

UPDATE: Dmitriy Loskutov suggested this - [When should XMLHttpRequest's onerror handler fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584318/when-should-xmlhttprequests-onerror-handler-fire)

Comment: this is the xy problem - this has nothing to do with promises at fault but with the xhr.

Comment: what do you mean by url is wrong

Comment: 'http://marsweather.ingenology.com/v1/archive/1' - I have just added '1' in the end - correct one is 'http://marsweather.ingenology.com/v1/archive/'

Comment: you have to check the status code.

Comment: Could you please give an example?

Comment: check `request.status`

Comment: it is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584318/when-should-xmlhttprequests-onerror-handler-fire. `onerror` only fire when it is network error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Promise` isn't at fault. You need to check appropriately for the `status` in your `onload` handler.

```
    request.onload = function(e){
        if (request.status === 200) {
            resolveFN(request.response);
        }
        else {
            rejectFN(...);
        }
        removeProcessing(); //this is for special notifcation disappear after 'onload'
    };
```

Comment: so I actually don't need 'onerror' - all code can be moved to 'onload' in order  to create an error when 'status' is not '200'?

Comment: @Dancyg it depends - theres other errors that don't come in `onload`. it depends on what your api returns

Comment: because when I just invoke getJSON like this
`getJSON('http://marsweather.ingenology.com/v1/latest/').then(function(response){
 //some code..
}).catch(function(err){
 console.log(err);
});`
it catches an error (for ex.'404 - not found'). but when it is inside the eventListener - it just doesn't use its own 'onerror' eventLtener.