# How to get error information in XmlHttpRequest error event

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, dom-events

I have simple code like that:

```
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.addEventListener('error', logError);
request.open('GET', 'www.someapi.com');
request.withCredentials = true;
request.send();
```

And logging is like that:

```
const logError = (error) => {
  console.log(`Error\nEvent:\n${JSON.stringify(error, null, 4)}`);
  // Code to log to server
};
```

Now what happens is that I get log messages with error, but there is like nothing meaningful in there, just `"isTrusted": true`. I would like to get more information on what is going on and why I get this error. E.g. in the console I see something like that when I fiddle connection drop:

`net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

But when it comes to javascript event, it's literally no meaningful information to figure out what is going on. E.g. I have read that CORS can cause it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584318/when-should-xmlhttprequests-onerror-handler-fire), but without any message it is very hard to figure out what is going on.

Comment: did you  check log in network tab

Comment: Network tab does indeed show all but the problem is that I cannot reproduce the problem locally, I just see it happens on the server, and I don't have enough info to understand why.

Answer (score -3):

**You can check the error log as follow :**

```
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onerror = function (e) {
                console.log(e);
                reject(new TypeError('Network request failed'));
            };
```