# xmlHttpRequest.onerror handler use case

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, onerror

What sort of situations could cause this handler to be called? I'm not finding any instance where this method throws an error.

I tried with the device offline, I get `xmlHttpRequest.status = 0` but no error.

Question is what sort of situations can I create in order to test functionality of this handler.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(),
  method = 'GET',
  url = 'https://developer.mozilla.org/';

xmlhttp.open(method, url, true);
xmlhttp.onerror = function () {
  console.log("** An error occurred during the transaction");
};
xmlhttp.send();
```

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequestEventTarget/onerror

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should XMLHttpRequest's onerror handler fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584318/when-should-xmlhttprequests-onerror-handler-fire)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your question is the perfect example. Just try your code from your web developer console while on this very page.

[image]

Here, try it yourself:

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(),
  method = 'GET',
  url = 'https://developer.mozilla.org/';

xmlhttp.open(method, url, true);
xmlhttp.onerror = function () {
  console.log("** An error occurred during the transaction");
};
xmlhttp.send();
```

When dealing with any network based IO all kinds of things could happen. Cross-Origin requests are only one. What if the server is offline, DNS lookup fails, a router between you and the server that is critical point of failure goes down?

Comment: onerror is only fired when an error occurs on the network level. Any HTTP codes, including 400 and over will *not* trigger onerror.

Comment: Just like Jonhan Gorter said, http response will not fire this event.

Comment: How to get a response?  For instance I want to detect when fileuristrict is not turned on which won't allow a file read.  How can I know there was an error?

Comment: There like is no HTTP error code if the server is offline, DNS lookup fails, or you can't route to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Since an XHR call is for a server response, onerror would come into play when there is an error at the server. Changing your client to be offline doesn't simulate a server error.

Suppose the server resource gets moved and the server responds with a 404 error? What if the server times out? What if the request itself is malformed and causes the server to throw an error?

Comment: I see, the malformed request is also an error. For timeout they have a separate handler and I'm not sure if timeout triggers error too. do you know https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/timeout