# ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED: Is there any way to catch an error using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, try-catch

I know that such a question has been asked before, but there was no answer. Do you guys know how to catch ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED? Also it would be nice if someone helps to find a way to redirect user if this error appears.

Here is my link to the website that throws such an error: https://t.me/tech_design

I tried to use `XMLHttpRequest` in console:

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET','HELLO',true);
xhr.send(); // After that we get an error!
Failed to load chrome-error://chromewebdata/HELLO: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

It might not throw an error in some regions, but still, how to catch this? And how to attach script to broken page?

Comment: `but there was no answer.`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45067892/xmlhttprequest-onerror-handler-use-case

Comment: @Keith thanks man!!